# Exchange information between controllers inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to register events like window-close, minimize, maximize and use it inside my controller inside content so I can clean up some things before window is closed. I've just an stupid idea with random ids and broadcast. Anything better?

### Window Controller

```
<div class="window">
   <div class="header">
      <a ng-click="minimize()">Minimize</a>
      <a ng-click="maximize()">Maximize</a>
      <a ng-click="close()">Close</a>
   <div class="content" ng-include="Controllers/someWindow.html"></div>
</div>
```

### Controllers/someWindow.html

```
<div ng-controller="SomeWindowCtrl">

</div>
```

Comment: A service generally works best for communicating across controllers.  You can have a service that manages the modal window, or even individual modal windows like `ui-bootstrap` does.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the `div.window` element into a directive (say, `my-window`) and expose a controller from it. Then, directives inside it can require `my-window` as parent, getting its controller as the fourth argument of the link function.

A concise example can be found [here](https://demisx.github.io/angularjs/directives/2014/11/25/angular-directive-require-property-options.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('EVENT_ID', data);
```

and

```
$rootScope.$on('EVENT_ID', function($event, data) {
    //event handler
});
```